# Intent is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have this Intent Code:

```
Intent arbeiten = new Intent(this, arbeiten.class);
startActivity(arbeiten);
```

but Eclipse tells me:

```
The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<arbeiten>) is undefined
```

Other (working) Intents in the same Project, but other Class looks like

```
Intent toolb = new Intent(this, ToolBox.class);
toolb.putExtra("json", json.toString());
startActivity(toolb);
```

And they are working...

The "Arbeiten"-Class looks like this:

```
package XXX;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class arbeiten extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code surrounding the Intent?

Comment: It is an Switch within the "case 2: break;"

Comment: The Intent Class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: maybe you cant name an intent similar to a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `this` refers to your `OnItemClickListener`. There are different ways of solving this. One way is to make a reference to the context of the activity like this:

```
Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //your code

    mContext = this;
}
```

Then in your `OnClickListener`, change it to this:

```
Intent arbeiten = new Intent(mContext, arbeiten.class);
startActivity(arbeiten);
```

Comment: IMHO it would be simpler to pass the class reference with `CustomUserClassName.this` this would also avoid the added variable

Comment: Yes, I think you're probably right. I normally need the context for something else, so do it that way out of habit.

Comment: I made it like this: `Intent arbeiten = new Intent(ToolBox.this, Arbeiten.class);`

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, it looks like you are creating the `Intent` from within your `OnClickListener`. To create the `Intent`, you have to pass a `Context`. You can probably achieve this using:

```
Intent arbeiten = new Intent(NameOfYourActivity.this, arbeiten.class);
startActivity(arbeiten);
```

(Where `NameOfYourActivity` is the outer class)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling it from inside a Listener, so `this` makes reference to the listener and not to the 'external' activity. Try with:

```
Intent arbeiten = new Intent(YourClassName.this, arbeiten.class);
startActivity(arbeiten);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), arbeiten.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all choose for your local Object's some different name, except then arbeiten, and make sure that you're calling the right "this", for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, arbeiten.class);
startActivity(intent);
```