# How to call custom intent page in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.xxx.MapRouteActivity.class);
this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

this will not working in `Phonegap`,I called in plugin execute method but it is force closing application,please can anyone tell how to call custom intent and from where to call this one.

I got error like this in logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(870): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-22
08-30 15:15:01.463: E/AndroidRuntime(870): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.camden.intenttest.MapRouteActivity
```

Comment: Instead of **this.ctx.startActivity(intent);**  use **startActivity(intent);**

Comment: thanks  for ur reply.i already tried but not working

Comment: can u post the error which u r getting..

Comment: follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517891/intent-is-not-working)

Comment: Do you actually have a reference to that Activity in your Android project?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead of:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.xxx.MapRouteActivity.class);
this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

This:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NameOfTheCurrentActivity.this, com.xxx.MapRouteActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Like:

```
Intent in = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```